# Query for returning properties from several entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using the entity framework database first to build a model of my database. Up to this point I have worked on single tables/entities and it has gone quite smooth to get the data with a query and saving it in a list in order to present the data.

Now I am in a situation where I need to join several tables and find myself in a bit of a struggle. I thougth I could simply join the entities I need since they have a foreign key to eachother, but I am having trouble finding a query that returns the set I want, which is basicly all columns from all tables.

In t-sql I would simply do a LEFT JOIN on the different tables on the keys. I have considered creating a view and then build the model on this view, but I have to be able to update the data as well and a view from the database is not so straight forward to update with the EF as far as I have understood.

I was hoping to do something like the query below, but since I need to update the different tables as well I was wondering if anyone has an elegant solution for how to do this. Or is it something I simply have not understood about joining in EF?

```
using(var _ctx = new EFEntities())
{
    var queryResult = from a in _ctx.a
    join b in _ctx.b
      on a.b_ID equals b.ID
    join c in _ctx.c
      on b.c_IDequals c.ID

    select new
    {
    //columns I want
    };
}
```

Comment: Are these one-to-one relationships?

Comment: They are one-to-many.

Comment: If they are one-to-many then don't the entities have enumerable properties for their many related entities already?

Comment: I agree with @neoistheone but if you really want to do this why not do `select new { a = a, b = b, c = c }`

Comment: There is no given method I have to do this. As long as I am able to read from the different entities with one query, and also do updates. I will looke more into the enumerable properties. Thought I already had, but I have probably overlooked something. Thank you so far and for quick response!

Comment: I feel kind of stupid, but I have to ask so I know if I understand you guys correctly. You mean I should be able to select f.ex
`select a.b_ID.b_description`
Cause I am not able to do that even though I have `public virtual b b{ get; set; }` in the a.cs file

Comment: @Nighty_- this could be because your `DbContext` has gone out of scope? Or your mappings are wrong? I suggest you start a new question if you're navigation properties are not working as you would expect.

Comment: Ok. I will investigate more over the weekend. Thanks @qujck.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned in the comments there should be navigation properties between your classes but if you really want to flatten the data but maintain objects that can be updated elsewhere then you could do something like this:

```
using(var _ctx = new EFEntities())
{
    var queryResult = from a in _ctx.a
    join b in _ctx.b
      on a.b_ID equals b.ID
    join c in _ctx.c
      on b.c_IDequals c.ID

    select new
    {
        a = a,
        b = b,
        c = c
    };
```

}